# Change the color of the text when text is too long (text-overflow: "ellipses")

Tags: css, reactjs

I would like to change the color of the text when the string is too long. If a string is too long, it will display '...' at the end with the color red otherwise the color will be black. I am not sure if it is possible to achieve this.

This is my CSS class

```
 textStyle:{
      whiteSpace: 'pre-line', 
      paddingTop:5,
      overflow: 'hidden',
      'text-overflow': 'ellipsis',
       display: '-webkit-box',
      '-webkit-line-clamp': 3,
      '-webkit-box-orient': 'vertical'

  }
```

My frontend

```
 String testString = "This is a long long text, it will show three dots when it has more than three lines..."

 <div className={classes.textStyle}>{testString}</div>
```

What it does is when the text is more than 3 lines, it will show '... at the end like below

```
This is a long long text,
it will show three dots when
it has more than three lines...
```

What I want is the change the whole text to font color to red when the above case happens. However, the above CSS will also change the color of the text when it only has one line

```
This is a long long text
```

Comment: Not possible with CSS. CSS can't detect overflow or ellipsis to apply any style such as you require. CSS styles an element based on a selector and there is no selector for an effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible with css only. It does not know if the text overflows.

With JS maybe you can check if the inner element has less height than the outer

```
.outer {
    white-space: pre-line;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}

<div className="outer"><span className="inner"> ...content </span></div>
```

The outer element will stop to grow on 3rd line, but the inner one will get all the height of the text. So if `outer.offsetHeight < inner.offsetHeight` that means the text overflows. This needs to be checked on resize as well because the element can change its width or height on windows resize

Something like this:

```
const [overflows, setOverflows] = useState(false)

useEffect(() => {

    const outer = ..., inner = ...  // get the elements with useRef

    const checkOverflow = () => {
        setOverflows(outer.offsetHeight < inner.offsetHeight)
    }
    
    const observer = new ResizeObserver(checkOverflow)
    observer.observe(inner) 
    checkOverflow()
    
    return () => {
        observer.disconnect()
    }
}, [])

...
<div className="outer" style={{color: overflows ? 'red' : 'black'}}>
    <span className="inner"> ...content </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is it possible to do this in React Component instead of React Hook?

Comment: React hooks are used inside React components. Do you mean class component? The logic is same, just use ```componentDidMount``` instead of ```useEffect``` and ```componentWillUnmount``` for cleanup

Answer (score 0):

```
const testString = "This is a long long text, it will show three dots when it has more than three lines...";

const isTextTooLong = testString.split('\n').length > 1;

  const textStyle = {
    whiteSpace: 'pre-line',
    paddingTop: 5,
    overflow: 'hidden',
    textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
    display: '-webkit-box',
    WebkitLineClamp: 3,
    WebkitBoxOrient: 'vertical',
    color: isTextTooLong ? 'red' : 'black', 
  };
```